# Encountering problems while executing : npm install exec-sync

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

Version info :

```
node@4.6.0
node-gyp@3.4.0
npm@2.15.9
```

I try to install the following dependencies :

```
 "canvas": "^1.1.6",
 "exec-sync": "^0.1.6",
 "fabric": "^1.6.0",
 "request": "^2.67.0",
 "word": "^0.2.4"
```

So i do an npm install the following dependencies are installed:

```
 "canvas": "^1.1.6",   
 "fabric": "^1.6.0",
 "request": "^2.67.0",
 "word": "^0.2.4"
```

But the exec-sync delivers the following error:

```
1443 verbose stack Error: ffi@1.2.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
1443 verbose stack Exit status 1
1443 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:217:16)
1443 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
1443 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
1443 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
1443 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
1443 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
1443 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
1443 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Im a litte bit lost at this point, i tried the following things:

1. Deleted all the node_modules and tried an fresh install;
2. Tried installing the modules seperately;

Is it a version problem of node.js  vs the  exec-sync build?, im lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

- CD to node_modules
- git clone https://github.com/jeremyfa/node-exec-sync edit
- open node-exec-sync/package.json to remove the ffi dependency line
- npm  install ./node-exec-sync

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed as a workaround to npm install for testing:

- removed `exec-sync` dependency from `package.json`
- `npm install ffi` (installs latest version ok)
- `git clone https://github.com/jeremyfa/node-exec-sync`
- edit `node-exec-sync/package.json` to remove the `ffi` dependency line
- `npm install ./node-exec-sync` then npm install finished ok

Comment: That works, thanks! Note that, you need to remove ffi from exec-sync dependency in order to build exec-sync. But to run exec-sync related program, you still need to install ffi separately. That's why I initially feel confused about your solution, but now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use node-exec-sync, it's very difficult to install, on every OS that I've tried, for different reasons.

Instead, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn , which doesn't have any of these unbuildable native dependencies. It's basically an all-around better replacement for `node-exec-sync` or the built-in `child_process` APIs.